# embed YouTube video - how did they do this?

Tags: javascript, flash, youtube, embed

at the time of writing Movember is fast approaching.

I've never seen a YouTube video embedded in a site so well before - there is no YouTube skin. Does anyone know how it was done?

http://au.movember.com/?slide=30sectvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML of that element is this:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="movytplayer" data="http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?enablejsapi=1&amp;playerapiid=ytplayer" width="100%" height="100%">
  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
  <param name="bgcolor" value="#cccccc"><param name="wmode" value="transparent">
</object>
```

This might be your key `http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?enablejsapi=1`, as it seems to enable  some sort of API (here's an unskinned player: http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?enablejsapi=1).

I'd look at that site's source and see what JS they are using to control the video.

---

I looked at the JS, and there are a few functions like this you can play with:

- `layout_tilePlay();`
- `layout_titleMute();`

Answer (score 4):

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/player_parameters.html